# How to get the highest and lowest mark from a row in the database

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to work out how to get the highest and lowest mark from a row in the database when the user clicks the search button. The code I have been trying to use is not working can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
int max = A[0];
for (int i =1; 1 < A.length; i++)
{
if (A[i] > max)
{
max = A [i];
}
}
return (max);
}
```

Overall I expect the user to enter a students ID and click the search button and will then display that specific students lowest and highest mark.

Comment: `SELECT MIN` and `SELECT MAX`.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp (found by googling for `SELECT MIN`).

Comment: The easiest way to do this is as part of your SQL select (which is what @mjwills has answered). What you have should get you the max value though. What's not working?

Comment: The reason it's not working because every answer is showing me how to get the min and max from an entire column. Whereas I just want it from one student's row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? You could just do Array.Sort(A), then var min = A[0] and var max = A[A.Length-1].

Comment: Yes, this is part of my assignment but I've been suck on it for a week now.

Comment: `Whereas I just want it from one student's row.` Please show us your database schema. From your description it sounds like you are storing multiple marks in a given row. This is _almost certainly_ a bad idea.

Comment: Its completely unclear what you are asking, What is `A`, what is in `A`, where is it defined, what has a database got to do with `A`. Unless you can add more **relevant information* and stop making people guess at the information you have left out, this question should be closed. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it on code side then first sort the array and min will be 0th index value of array and max will be last index value of the array,

```
double[] marksArr;
Array.Sort(marksArr);
double min=marksArr[0];
double max=marksArr[marksArr.length];
```

hope it will work.

Comment: I've just tried this code but array.sort(marksarr); it's saying its an unassigned local variable.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by populate?

Comment: "Put data in it".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double[] marksArr＝new Double[4];
marksArr[0]=5;
marksArr[1]=2;
marksArr[2]=7;
marksArr[3]=4;
Array.Sort(marksArr);
double min=marksArr[0];
double max=marksArr[marksArr.length];
```