# How to get the max and min values from a table row not a column in a database

Tags: c#

I have a table in my database with a number of different students names in one column and a column for each subject marks eg- Course 1, Course 2 - Course 10. I'm trying to find the min and max Course score from a student that is chosen from the database. Does this make sense?

I have been stuck on this problem for over a week because all the answers I keep finding are how to find the min and max value from a column where as I need it for a row.

Please help me I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I assume this is also your question that you asked earlier under another account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469750/how-to-get-the-highest-and-lowest-mark-from-a-row-in-the-database

Comment: This is your second attempt and its not impressive. please think of it from our point of view, we have no idea how you are querying the db, whether you are using an ORM ect, what the structure is after the query... please put your exact table structure, the query any code, and any other relevant information... If you do, this will be answered in minutes

Comment: The reason you find this hard to do in SQL, is because your database design is not normalized. So either normalize your database (3 tables, `Students`, `Courses` and `Grades`), or find the min/max in application code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int[] max_min_rowvalue(DataRow dr)
    {
        int[] i_array = new int[2];

        List<int> lst_values = new List<int>();

        //Start at 1 to avoid Student field which is presumably a varchar field
        //Presumes the course scores are int
        //Add null checks if required
        for(int i = 1; i <= dr.ItemArray.Length -1; i++)
        {
            if (lst_values.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(dr[i])) == false) lst_values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr[i]));
        }

        lst_values.Sort();

        i_array[0] = lst_values[0];
        i_array[1] = lst_values[lst_values.Count - 1];

        return i_array;
    }
```

Testing:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Student");
dt.Columns.Add("Course1");
dt.Columns.Add("Course2");
dt.Columns.Add("Course3");
dt.Columns.Add("Course4");
dt.Columns.Add("Course5");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
object[] rowarray = new object[6];
rowarray[0] = "Paul";
rowarray[1] = 8;
rowarray[2] = 2;
rowarray[3] = 10;
rowarray[4] = 10;
rowarray[5] = 4;
dr.ItemArray = rowarray;
int[] i_test = max_min_rowvalue(dr);
Debug.WriteLine(i_test[0]);
Debug.WriteLine(i_test[1]);
```

Returns 2 and 10